# How to create Airflow read only users?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there a way to create read only users in Airflow ? I see there is some discussion about that is Airflow 2.0 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Airflow+2.0 
Does anyone know if that has been incorporated in 1.9 ? We are currently using 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

There’s work ongoing in this PR:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3015

Design (early):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Airflow+RBAC+proposal

Comment: Thanks @jornh, so it seems like we need to wait for 2.0 release.

Comment: You’re welcome, yes or rather 1.10 it seems https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/5cad655532abb4972c9cf997ab0a82d91e58eee223f0481551810b52@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it's not available right now. Maybe at the next major version

Comment: Thanks Antoine, so it seems like we need to wait for 2.0 release. do you know if there is any expected release date ?